# Write metacharacters to a list

Tags: python

I try to encapsulate regex metacharaters to a list

```
In [1]: mc = ['^', '$', '[', ']', '{', '}', '-', '?', '*', '+', '(', ')', '|', '\']
```

Enter and get errors

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: In [1]: mc = ['^', '$', '[', ']', '{', '}', '-', '?', '*', '+', '(', ')', '|', r'\']

Comment: You need to escape your backslash: ```'\\'```

Comment: Does `r` is introduced by the latest version of python @CodeCupboard

Comment: @CodeCupboard ```r'\'``` doesn't work as you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the backslash, which is an escape character. The correct representation of a single backslash would be `'\\'` or `"\\"`.

While all the answers above seem to work, for readability it might be better to write

```
mc = list("^$[]{}-?*+()|\\")
```

This makes it much easier to see which characters are being used, reducing visual clutter at very little cost.

Comment: That could be a nice comment, but not an answer to the asked question

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it resolves the problem just as effectively as the other answers. I've added a comment about the backslash for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
mc = ['^', '$', '[', ']', '{', '}', '-', '?', '*', '+', '(', ')', '|', '\\']
```

You need to escape the final backslash `\` with another one, as in the list above `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash next to a " ' " is an escape sequence

```
In [1]: mc = ['^', '$', '[', ']', '{', '}', '-', '?', '*', '+', '(', ')', '|', '\\']
```

Comment: Should be ```'\\'```. ```r'\'``` is not going to work.

Comment: Correct. There is no way to end a raw string with a single backslash.

Comment: Thank you - everyday is a school day

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the final backslash:

```
mc = ['^', '$', '[', ']', '{', '}', '-', '?', '*', '+', '(', ')', '|', '\\']
```

In your example, the backslash is escaping the last quote, so it's not valid python.